# How to save an image in the required folder

Tags: asp.net

I need to save images in certain folder of my application:

```
string path="E:\AJAXEnabledWebSite1\images\gallery"
```

I have dropdowns - there are 4 options:

1. images-1
2. images-2
3. images-3
4. images-4

file upload  control:from here  need to get the  file  name along  with the extension

if  user selectes   images-2  as  value in dropdown
  then we  need to  concatentae

file.saveas(path+ddl.selected .value+filename)
if  i am  doing like this means  files ae not getting saved in the  destination folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
string path = "/images/gallery";
file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(path, + "/" + ddl.Selected + "/") + fileName);
```

this will automatically map the correct physical directory on your server and save the file in the appropriate folder.